# Move files that are more than 30 days older

Tags: powershell

This is what we I have tried: looks like it is deleting files from the source folder that is more than 30 days old and moving to target folder.

```
$source = "N:\Name\Source\Processed"
$dest = "N:\Name\Source\Archive\"

# Create the Archive folder if it doesn't exist</br>
if (-not (Test-Path $dest)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $dest
}

Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}|Move-Item -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.Name} -Force
```

Do you see any issues with this code?

Comment: Just looking for a clarification. Are you wanting to copy (keep the file in the source and move to the destination) or move (file moves from source to destination making it look like it was deleted from the source).

Comment: I am moving the files from source to destination after some of the files are 30 days old,

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what, specifically, isn't working as you expect and, specifically, what you expect instead.

Comment: I don't see issues in the code and tested it successfully. I however don't understand the nee of the Join-Path. $dest should suffice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not having any issues as such and it is working in the test environment. Just wanted to clarify since it will be applied in production environment. How else would you modify the code  Join-Path. $dest instead of ```Get-ChildItem $source -File -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)}|Move-Item -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.Name} -Force```

Comment: If you want to _preview_ the operation add the [common `-WhatIf` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-whatif) to your `Move-Item` call. Since it's sufficient to specify the target _directory_ for a move operation and you've ensured the destination directory's existence, you can replace `-Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.Name}` with `-Destination $dest`

Comment: As a general tip: Note that "Does this code do what I think it does?" questions aren't really [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site.